# Redirecting request from one folder to another in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How do I redirect a request from one folder to another?

For example: when I get request to `localhost/folder1` then it should redirect to `localhost/folder2`.

Need some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder1(.*)$ /folder2$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 
`RewriteRule ^subdirectory/(.*)$ /anotherdirectory/$1 [R=301,NC,L]` in you .htaccess file